# Flutter/Dart: how to hint text on entered keyword

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say I have a list of strings:
`[ apple, ananas, banana]`

I want to make a text input that for example when I write `a` the input field would automatically show the word `ananas` with `nanas` being less visible, so that the user can see it is a hint. Continuing the example, if the next word in the input would be `ap` then it would hint towards `apple`, and if ENTER is pressed the word `apple` should be the actual value of the text field.

Comment: Great. What did you try so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Is this a requirement? As an alternative, you can use a dropdown with suggestions, there is already a built-in solution for this.

Comment: try to add onChange and check for the text if is same as in hits list  and if is so update your ui